# SQLite 3 C++ Quiz - Comparing user's response to existing database

Tags: html, c++, sqlite

I'm trying to write a C++ program, using SQLite. Which allows a user to select their preferences for a hotel room. And the program compares the user's answers to that of the existing values held within a database.

The user will be choosing from drop down menus on a HTML+CSS web page, however I am unsure how to link the user's response to C++. Also I struggled to find any SQLite tutorials which could help me with my situation. Do I need to create the table which holds the hotel's values first?

Tried using an `sqlite3_open` command, also execute statements. However everything I try leads to error messages and I'm stumped.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sqlite3.h> 

sqlite_open("HotelProject.db", &db);

sqlite3_exec(db,"CREATE TABLE hotel_tbl (name, location, rating)");
sqlite3_exec(db,"INSERT INTO hotel_tbl (name, location, rating)" \ 
    "VALUES ('x','y','z')");

sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT * FROM hotel_tbl");
sqlite3_close(db);
return 0;
```

It's been a while since I last used C++ and it hasn't all come back to me... Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this just a part of your code (or parts) or are you missing `main` function?

Comment: @barbsan this is all I have so far. I really need guidance for how to establish the main function again. Is that the reason the open and exec commands won't work?

Comment: I recommend you to go through some tutorial, like [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm) or even some basic c++, and compare your code with those examples

Answer (score 0):

Compare your code to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sqlite3.h"

int main()
{
  sqlite3 *db;
  sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

  int rc = sqlite3_open("HotelProject.db", &db);
  if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    std::cout << "Failed to open database.";
    return 1;
  }
  rc = sqlite3_exec(db,
                    "CREATE TABLE hotel_tbl (name, location, rating);",
                    NULL, NULL, NULL);
  if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    std::cout << "Failed to create table.";
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 1;
  }
  rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "INSERT INTO hotel_tbl VALUES (@x, @y, @z);",
                          -1, &stmt, NULL);
  if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    std::cout << "Failed to compile query statement.";
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 1;
  }
  rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, "x", -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
  if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    std::cout << "Failed to bind paramter.";
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 1;
  }
  rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, "y", -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
  if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    std::cout << "Failed to bind paramter.";
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 1;
  }
  rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, "z", -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
  if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    std::cout << "Failed to bind paramter.";
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 1;
  }
  rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
  if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
    std::cout << "Failed to insert row in table.";
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 1;
  }
  sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
  sqlite3_close(db);
  return 0;
}
```

I don't think it's all going to "just come back to you". Plainly, you have quite a lot of reading ahead of you.